# asp classic how to trap errors when connecting to an oracle linked server

Tags: sql, oracle, asp-classic, linked-list

I have a query in classic ASP like this:

```
sql_test="select * from Openquery(it_test, 'select * from IT_DB.HOST')
```

the problem is that I want to test the connection to the linked server before executing it and getting an error on the page.

If the connection to the linked server doesn't work (ex: db down) I can execute a query on the local SQL server 2000 db avoiding getting an error on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use this code...

```vb
'GetDataSet error columns...
const C_ERROR               = "ERROR"               'Used when an error is generated - to be fed to the comsuming routine
const C_NO_DATA             = "NO_DATA"             'Used when no data is returned to a consuming routine
const C_COL_IDENTIFIER      = 0
const C_COL_ERROR_ID        = 1
const C_COL_ERROR_MESSAGE   = 2
const C_COL_SQL             = 3
const C_COL_CONNECTION      = 4

'GetDataSet
'   Returns a table of data based on the supplied SQL statement and connection string.
'Parameters:
'   sqlString (string) - The SQL string to be sent.
'   connString (string) - The database connection string.
'Usage:
'   dataSet = GetDataSet(sqlString, connString)
'Description:
'   This function generates a table of information in a 2 dimensional array.  The first dimension represents the columns
'   and the second the rows.  If an error occurs while the routine is executing the array and the base index (0,0) is set 
'   to C_ERROR, (0,1) to the VBScript error index, and (0,2) to the VBScript error description.
function GetDataSet(sqlString, connString)
    'Initialise...
    dim returnVal, rsData
    on error resume next
        'Define and open the recordset object...
        set rsData = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        rsData.Open sqlString, connString, 0, 1, 1
        'Initialise an empty value for the containing array...
        redim returnVal(0,0)
        returnVal(0,0) = C_NO_DATA
        'Deal with any errors...
        if not rsData.EOF and not rsData.BOF then
            'Store the data...
            returnVal = rsData.GetRows()
            select case err.number
                case 3021   'No data returned
                    'Do nothing as the initial value will still exist (C_NO_DATA)
                case 0      'No error
                    'Do nothing as data has been returned
                case else
                    redim returnVal(4,0)
                    returnVal(C_COL_IDENTIFIER,0) = C_ERROR
                    returnVal(C_COL_ERROR_ID,0) = err.number
                    returnVal(C_COL_ERROR_MESSAGE,0) = err.description
                    returnVal(C_COL_SQL,0) = sqlString
                    returnVal(C_COL_CONNECTION,0) = connString
            end select
        end if
        'Tidy up...
        rsData.close
        set rsData = nothing
    on error goto 0
    'Return the array...
    GetDataSet = returnVal
end function
```

To get my data sets.  It returns an array that you can man handle (ermm ... woman-handle?) as you like.

If there's an error the details are returned in the appropriate elements of the array.

Comment: I would tend to avoid closing `ADODB.Recordset` in an `If` statement you should do the `EOF` check first then close the recordset then use `IsArray()` to check you have a valid array returned by `GetRows()`.

Comment: @Lankymart: Good point. I'll modify that.  To be honest I bashed it together years ago to fill a gap.  Thanks Lanky.

Comment: @rosy: No problem, Rosy.  Good luck.  Would you mind clicking the tick for the answer if it's good for you? Thanks :o)