# classic asp checkbox state as checkbox

Tags: asp-classic

I have not used checkboxes before and need some help.  I have a classic asp/html page.  I have an unknown number of people and there are 3 checkboxes for each person.  The user needs to check certain boxes based on information shown on the page.  I need to set some values on the same page based on which checkboxes are checked.  I've tried several ways and have not had any luck.

There is a loop that displays each persons name and these three checkboxes:
`<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="chkden" name="chkden" onclick="chkden();" value=<%=strempdental%>/></td> 
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="chkort" name="chkort" onclick="chkort();" value=<%=strOrtPlan%>/></td>

<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="chkvis" name="chkvis" onclick="chkvis();" value=<%=strempvision%>/></td>`

Here is the javascript I have at the top of the page.  Neither of the options shown for Javascript work.

```
function chkden()
{
streesubden.value = checkbox.checked ? strempdental.value : '';
}
function chkort()
{
  if(document.getElementById('chkort').checked)
        streesubort.value = strortplan :'';
}
function chkvis()
{
  if(document.getElementById('chkvis').checked)
        streesubvis.value = strempvision :'';
}
```

e.g if "chkden" is checked then I need to set streesubden = strempdental.  If it's not checked then streesubden will be blank.  I need to do this before I submit to the SQL table.

Comment: If there is an unknown number of people are there multiple instances of the same checkbox? If so, then you need to refer to them in an array... if you confirm I will post answer how to refer and set arrays like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to auto-generate the checkboxes using Classic ASP and use the data item's ID as the differentiation between them, like so...

```vbs
<%
Dim data, row
Const C_COL_RECORD_ID = 0
Const C_COL_NAME = 1
data = GetDataSetAsArray() 'Just used as an arbitrary method for recovering the data.

For row = 0 to UBound(data, 2) 'Loop through the array rows.
    %>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkYes<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" name="chkYes<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkNo<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" name="chkNo<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkMaybe<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" name="chkMaybe<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" />
    <label><%=data(C_COL_NAME, row)%> <!-- Write the name to the page --></label>
<%
Next 'row
%>
```

Note that this is a very quick and easy way of doing it. If you need more information in there from your data then you'll have to sort that out.

When it comes to working with the check boxes they will be named and numbered to the person's record id, like so...

> chkYes1, chkNo1, chkMaybe1
>
> chkYes2, chkNo2, chkMaybe2
>
> ...
>
> chkYes[n], chkNo[n], chkMaybe[n]

Obviously this is going to be dependant on your record ids, so they may not be as serial as I have demonstrated above.

**-- EDIT --**

Actually, this goes hand in hand with a post I've just made. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876954/referencing-unchecked-checkboxes-with-vbscript-causes-an-error/25890165#25890165) and copy the `GetPostData()` function. Pulling the information back will be something like this:

```
Dim checkValue
checkValue = GetPostData("chkMaybe" & personId, "") <> ""
```

The `checkValue` will contain either `true` or `false`.

Obviously you could expand this to reload all of the `personId`s and loop through them to pull the different check box values.

**--EDIT--**

The `name` and `id` attributes really need a prefix to be clear as to their intent (if you're only assigning the record ID then every control will have a duplicate ID in the same visual row). Secondly, `<%= %>` is used to (`Response.`)write values to the page.  Therefore, something like:

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName<%=data(C_COL_RECD_ID, row)%>" name="txtName<%=data(C_COL_RECD_ID, row)%>" />
```

Would be appropriate - notice the `txtName` just before the `<%=data(C_COL_RECD_ID, row)%>`.  Likewise, if you were referring to a check box you could use the following:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkYes<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" name="chkYes<%=data(C_COL_RECORD_ID, row)%>" />
```

**PS:**
If it helps, I've posted a piece of code [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401618/asp-classic-how-to-trap-errors-when-connecting-to-an-oracle-linked-server/25405064#25405064) that will read data from a database, given the SQL and connection strings, and return the data in an array.  It also traps and reports errors - may be useful.

To use it:

```vbs
Dim sql, conn, data
sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
conn = "MyDbConnection;whatever"
Data = GetDataSet(sql, conn)
```

Then to error handle...

```vbs
If Data(0, 0) = C_ERROR Then
    'Handle error...
    Response.Write(Data(C_COL_ERROR_ID, 0) & "<br />" & Data(C_COL_ERROR_MESSAGE, 0) & "<br />")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I will give that a try. Alski - Yes, there will be multiple people, all with have these 3 checkboxes.

Comment: Paul - if I'm understanding this correctly, C_COL_RECORD_ID is chkden, chkort, chkvis (in my example) and the C_COL_NAME_ID is the persons id number?

Comment: No - `C_COL_RECORD_ID` will point to the first (and `C_COL_NAME` the second) 'column' in the array (*please note that the `_ID` on the end of the name column is actually a typo*). It is assumed that the data here is obtained using the `GetRows` method of the ADO `RecordSet` object. The `GetRows` method returns the data into a 2 dimensional array, the first rank being the 'columns' and the second the 'rows'. To get the total number of rows in the dataset (array) use `UBound(data, 2)`.

Comment: Please bear with me, this is more complicated than what I usually work with.  It is not currently using GetRows.  There are two tables, employee and dependent.  The first person is always from the employee table so I'm just doing response.write to display that person.  I can get the dependents from the other table using GetRows.  I will try to get everyone in GetRows and go from there.

Comment: I'm getting the id, first name, last name, relation, dental, ortho, vision in the GetRows; the last 3 are the checkboxes. I'm getting an error:Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub on this line  `<input type="text" id="<%data(c_col_recd_id, row)%>" name="<%data(c_col_recd_id, row)%>" /> `  Did I miss something?

Comment: @amiel: Morning! I've posted an update, amiel, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I've had a few things come up this morning but will work on it this afternoon.  I appreciate all of your help!  I inherited this project and it's more complex than what I usually do.  But I'm learning!